# What special materials can be used with a Sugliin?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, weapons, special-materials

> This massive polearm consists of several sets of sharpened caribou and/or megaloceros antlers affixed to a long wooden shaft.

Ah, the sugliin, such a silly weapon. But so cool-looking. Many special materials specify that they can only be added to metal weapons, which the sugliin is not. What special materials *can* be used with it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this needs a bit of adjudication by the DM: a lot of sources do not state explicitly that the material can only be used if the base weapon normally is made mostly from metal, but it still is implied, because the materials are described as a surrogate material for metal, or are described as being forged.

So in your case, with the Slugiin, the real question may be: do you require a Slugiin that still uses natural antlers, affixed to a staff of some other material? Or do you accept lookalike-antlers that are in reality forged out of metal? Based on the answer, different materials will suffice. Whats more, a substantial portion of that weapon is the antler part, so the DM will have to decide if replacing the staff with Darkwood (for example) is sufficient to convey the material's benefits to the weaopn or not. Do they consider the Slugiin more to be like a spear, or more like a battleaxe?

Here are [special materials](https://www.d20srd.org/srd/specialMaterials.htm) that do not have a restriction to metal weapons and might be useful, in particular to the staff (although you could make a staff from many metals, too), and might fit to such a low-tech weapon, northern culture too.

- **Darkwood**. (*Core Rules*)
- **Bronzewood**. (*Arms & Equipmment Guide*)
- **Bone** (*Dragon Magazine* 319 p. 39, from the Dark Sun setting)
- **Stone** (*Dragon Magazine* 319 p. 40, from the Dark Sun setting)
- **Blue Ice** (*Frostburn* p. 80) - described to be forged, so depends on if you are OK with forging parts of the weapon - the staff, or the entire thing
- **Rimefire Ice** ("*It cannot be used to make any appreciable armor, but it can be used to create any weapon that is normally made out of wood (or nearly completely of wood, as in the case of a spear or javelin*", so depends if your DM in generous and considers the slugiin more of a spear than an axe).
- **Frystalline** (*Book of Exalted Deeds*, p. 38) Works for any weapon, making it good aligned.

I'm skipping a few materials like *stygian ice* that are described as exteremely brittle and requiring saving throws to avoid the weapon from shattering, and a load of special metal-replacements, that could apply if the whole weapon were to be forged from metal. You can find a more exhaustive list of special materials that can be used for weapons [here](https://forums.giantitp.com/showthread.php?442820-Special-Materials-Index).